# i want to disable date and time from current date and time, and working with custom date and time in angular and html, for date i am able to disabled

Tags: javascript, html, angular, dynamic, disabled-input

```
<div class="date-time-para">
                                    <div class="box-date">
                                        <label class="font-weight-bold"> Select Date {{notificationDetails.scheduled_date}}</label>
                                        <!-- <input type="date" formControlName="notificationDate" placeholder="Select Date" class="input-sample" placeholder="Select Date" [(ngModel)]="notificationDetails.scheduled_date"> -->
                                        <input type="date" formControlName="notificationDate" [ngModel]="notificationDetails.scheduled_date | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'" [min]="currentDate" />


                                    </div>
                                    <div class="box-date">
                                        <label class="font-weight-bold">Select Time</label>
                                        <!-- <input type="time" formControlName="notificationTime" placeholder="Select Date" class="input-sample" placeholder="Select Date" [(ngModel)]="notificationDetails.scheduled_time"> -->

                                        <input type="time" formControlName="notificationTime" [ngModel]="notificationDetails.scheduled_time" [min]="currentTime" />


                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

but same logic method i also implemented for time, but not be able to disabled past time from current time, can any one help ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use [(ngModel)] correctly , you are using both formGroup and ngModel at the same time which is again not necessary , you can go with any one approach .

Comment: actually same code is working with date, the previous date from current is disabled but pass should be disabled from current time is not working

Comment: you need to check the format of the current time that you are using , do a console log and check the format , if they are different you should convert it to specific format